# Change Keyboard Layout in TTY Permanently

Tags: console, keymap, tty

How can I change the keyboard layout in the **TTY** aka text mode reached through the combinations Ctrl+Alt+F1 through F6 **permanently**?

I tried sudo `echo 'KEYMAP=de' > /etc/conf.d/keymap` and `echo 'KEYMAP=de' > /etc/vconsole.conf` without success.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_console

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I forgot to mention that I edited the vconsole.conf also like this `echo 'KEYMAP=de' > /etc/vconsole.conf`.

Comment: Never mind, I just double-checked. I had a typo KEYNAP :D. Answering the question as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo 'KEYMAP=de' | sudo tee /etc/vconsole.conf
```

does the job, provided you don't make any typos. You may confirm with

```
cat /etc/vconsole.conf
```

Answer (score 4):

Your idea is correct, just the required command is off. `sudo echo > whatever` only executes `echo` with elevated privileges, the redirect is applied by the shell and so is not elevated. To write with sudo privileges, a common idiom is to pipe to `tee` and elevate that with `sudo`, so your command would become:

```
echo 'KEYMAP=de' | sudo tee /etc/vconsole.conf
```

An alternative would be to edit the file with your editor of choice launched with `sudo`.

If you only want to append to a file, you may use `tee -a`, or to modify a files contents use some other utility such as sed:

```
sudo sed -i 's/\(KEYMAP\).*/\1=dvorak-de/' /etc/vconsole.conf
```